# Are the variables inside the parentheses preceding callback functions in Flutter passed as arguments into those callback functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

In general, and in these examples for clarity, what is the nature of the parentheses and their contents (contents being `context` in Ex1 and nothing in Ex2)?

Ex1.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) {
        return CartModel();
    },
),
```

Ex2.

```
FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
        print("yay button")
    }
),
```

As far as I understand, the code inside the `{ }` brackets are callback functions that are executed only when the `create` and `onPressed` methods of some instances of the `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `FlatButton` classes are executed, respectively.

What is the nature of the contents of the parentheses? **Are they variables that are passed as arguments into the callback function?**

If they are passed as arguments into the callback function, why isn't the syntax of the first example instead:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: CartModel(context),
),
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: CartModel(context),
),
```

This is a named variable ("create") taking a `CartModel` as argument which has been created by given `context` as a constructor parameter.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) {
        return CartModel();
    },
),
```

This is a named variable ("create") taking a `CartModel Function(Context)` as argument. This function can be called anytime and multiple times by the `ChangeNotifierProvider`. When `ChangeNotifierProvider` are calling the method it will give a `Context` as argument to the method which it can use.

**Update with example**

Here is a small code example showing the behavior:

```
class A {
  B Function() createB;
  B b;

  A.callback({B Function() create}) : createB = create {
    print('Class A created');
  }

  A.value({B create}): b = create {
    print('Class A created');
  }

  void init() {
    b = createB();
  }
}

class B {
  B() {
    print('Class B created');
  }
}

void main() {
  A.value(create: B());
  // Class B created
  // Class A created

  final a = A.callback(create: () => B());
  // Class A created

  a.init();
  // Class B created
}
```

Comment: So is one of the main differences that in the first case, a `CartModel` object comes into existence at the point the `ChangeNotifierProvider` had its `create` variable assigned, while in the second case, no `CartModel` object yet exists, but the create variable now refers to a function that will create a `CartModel` using argument `context` if called? Does that mean that now, in the second case, `cnpInstance.create(context)` will create and return a `CartModel(context)`, where `cnpInstance` is a `ChangeNotifierProvider` object?

Comment: I will post an example later which shows the difference. But yes, in the first example in my post the object is created and sent as parameter where we in the second example just gives a method where we don't care when this is called.